# Python: Using a loop to iterate through one column of a spreadsheet, inserting it into a url and then saving the data

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

hope you're all keeping safe.

I'm trying to create a stock trading system that takes tickers from a spreadsheet, searches for those tickers on Yahoo finance, pulls, and then saves the historical data for the stocks so they can be used later.

I've got it working fine for one ticker, however I'm slipping up conceptually when it comes to doing it in the for loop.

This is where I've got so far:

I've got an excel spreadsheet with a number of company tickers arranged in the following format:

```
Ticker    Name
WMT       Walmart
AMZN      Amazon
AAPL      Apple
CVS       CVS Health
```

After reading these into a variable, I've created the following series:

```
p_ticker = p_data['Ticker']
```

I've got a simplistic 'webscraper' to look on Yahoo finance and pull data for one ticker:

```
ticker = 'AAPL'
scrape_string = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1=1480636740&period2=1606867140&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"

output = pd.read_csv(scrape_string)
output
```

I'm now trying to make it work for the contents of the spreadsheet, rather than one ticker; this is what I have attempted:

```
for ticker in p_ticker:
    scrape_string = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1=1480636740&period2=1606867140&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    ticker_data = {ticker:scrape_string}

    output = pd.read_csv(scrape_string)
    output

{'CVS': 'query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/…'}
```

Any idea how to make it iterate through each and get the dictionary working?

Comment: the 'ticker' variable contains all the tickers, use the 'tick' variable instead

Comment: Thanks, now the for loop works to an extent, now I suppose I need to create a variable each time it moves through a ticker on the loop.

Comment: Yes, you can make a dictionary for the results, with `tick` as the key.

Comment: With the addition of ticker_data = {ticker:scrape_string}, I've managed to get it to tie the ticker to a result as follows: {'CVS': 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/CVS?period1=1480636740&period2=1606867140&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'} However it's still ending on the last ticker on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for tick in p_ticker` works like this:
`p_ticker` is a list, and so can be iterated over. `for tick` does that - it takes the first thing and sets the value `tick` to it. Then in your next line, you have a brand new variable `ticker` that you are setting to `p_ticker`. But `p_ticker` is the whole list.

You want just the one value from it, which you already assigned to `tick`. So get rid of the `ticker=p_ticker` line, and in your `scrape_string`, use `tick` instead of `ticker`.

And then when it gets to the bottom of the loop, it comes back to the top, and sets `tick` to the next value in `p_ticker` and does it all again.

Also, your `scrape_string` line should be indented with everything else in the for-loop

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment; it's of great assistance. However, what it's doing is stopping on the final ticker, CVS; so I assume I need to create a variable to hold the data for each Ticker for when the data is pulled?

Comment: Yea, how it is it will just set `output` to the pandas readout and then not really do anything with it. You could make `output` a list and each time you go through the loop append the result the the list, and then do whatever you do with it.

output = []
output.append = pd.read_csv(...)

Then when you get out of the loop you'll have your whole output list with whatever the dataframes are, and go from there.